# Let $I$ be a prime ideal. Show that $f^{-1}(I)$ is a prime ideal of $R$. Is this also true for maximal ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm solving some exercises to prepare for my ring theory exam.

> Let $f:R→R'$ be a ring homomorphism, with $f(1)=1$, and $R,R'$
>   commutative rings with $1$. Let $I$ be a prime ideal. Show that
>   $f^{-1}(I)$ is a prime ideal of $R$. Is this also true for maximal
>   ideals? Prove or disprove.

I was able to prove this for prime ideals. But I don't know how to prove anything for maximal ideals. I think it is not true. But I find it hard to think of a counterexample.

Comment: $R = \mathbb{Z}$, $R' = \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Hmm maybe $(0)$ is maximal in $\mathbb{Q}$. I'm not sure.

Comment: How many ideals does a field have? Alternatively, an ideal $I$ in $R'$ is maximal iff $R'/I$ has what property?

Comment: Oh wait of course. A field has only the ideals $(0)$ and $R$. Then it follows. Thanks !

Comment: @DanielFischer Now I only need to prove it is a ringhomomorphism. But that is trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### $I$ a prime ideal $⇒$ $f^{-1}(I)$ a prime ideal

Suppose $I$ is a prime ideal. Then we know that $I≠R'$. We need to prove that $f^{-1}(I)≠R$. Suppose $f^{-1}(I)=R$. Then $f(1)=1 \in f^{-1}(I)$. So then $1 \in I$. And then $I=R'$.

Let $x,y \in R$ with $xy \in f^{-1}(I)$. Then $f(xy) \in I$. Then $f(x),f(y) \in I$. Then $x,y\in f^{-1}(I)$.

#### $I$ a maximal ideal $\not ⇒$ $f^{-1}(I)$ a maximal ideaal

Take the ring homomorphism $f : ℤ →\mathbb{Q} : x ↦ x$. As $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, therefore $(0)$ is a maximal ideal. But $f^{-1}((0))=(0)$ is not a maximal ideal because $ℤ$ is not a field.

Answer (score 4):

*Here is a possibly different way to prove the result for prime ideals, and it will help us determine a sufficient condition for the inverse image of a maximal ideal to be maximal.*

Let $f:A\to B$ be any commutative ring homomorphism, and let $\mathfrak b$ be any ideal of $B$. Then $\mathfrak a=f^{-1}\mathfrak b$ is an ideal of $A$ such that $f$ determines an injection $$\varphi:A/\mathfrak a\to B/\mathfrak b$$ This is basically the lattice theorem from group theory. Now, an ideal $\mathfrak q\subset B$ is prime if and only if $B/\mathfrak q$ is an integral domain. Let $\mathfrak p=f^{-1}\mathfrak q$ and note that $A/\mathfrak p$ embeds $B/\mathfrak q$. Since a subring of an integral domain is in turn an integral domain, $\mathfrak p$ is necessarily prime.

Now, an ideal $\mathfrak n\subset B$ is maximal if and only if $B/\mathfrak n$ is a field. Moreover, if we set $\mathfrak m$ to be the preimage of $\mathfrak n$, $A/\mathfrak m$ embeds the field $B/\mathfrak n$. So far so good. But the problem is that subrings of fields are not necessarily fields; this is the only reason why we cannot draw the same conclusion with maximal ideals as we did with prime ideals. However, it can be seen that if $f$ is **surjective**, then the embedding $\varphi$ is surjective--hence, $\varphi$ is an isomorphism--and $A/\mathfrak m$ is a **field**.